# Unmarshalling Error after convert XMLGregorianCalendar to LocalDate (yyyy-MM-dd)

Tags: java, soap, osgi, localdate, xmlgregoriancalendar

Hello everyone and thanks for your time!

Gonna try to get to the point as simple as possible:
I have **REST** and **SOAP** webservices.

REST has a **LocalDate birthdate** field in the request model, and SOAP has a **XMLGregorianCalendar birthdate** field in the request model.

I want to create for example a Student, I send the SOAP Request in SoapUI, the body will have the XMLGregorianCalendar birthdate and that need to be converted to LocalDate to be processed.

It only works with (yyyy-MM-dd), if i type (yyyy/MM/dd) it wont work... it gives me a Unmarshalling Error: yyyy/MM/dd

What I already tried:

**student.setBirthdate(LocalDate.parse(studentSOAP.getBirthdate().toXMLFormat()));**

**student.setBirthdate(studentSOAP.getBirthdate().toGregorianCalendar().toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate());**

I even tried to change the field type to String and then use:

**DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
            student.setBirthdate(LocalDate.parse(studentSOAP.getBirthdate(), formatter));**

but it says it cannot parse text "yyyy/MM/dd" at index 4

The adapter is out of option too since it doesnt support a large amount of formats...

Comment: Any particular reason why you don’t want to type yyyy-MM-dd (for example 1998-07-22)?

Comment: It's a work im doing and I can't tell the user to just use that format... the user should be able to put any format he wants...